# Will a service use windows credential manager when running as that user?

Tags: windows, service, windows-authentication

I've installed some generic credentials into the windows credential manager. I've also installed a service that runs as this user account.

Will the service have access to use these credentials? I need the service to have access to our private bitbucket repositories via https. But I'm getting inconsistent results. Is it possible that the process integrity level is preventing access to the wcm?